# Add directory containing a dll to gradle as path?

Tags: java, gradle, dll, jar

I've been given a .jar that calls to a .dll to use in a project.

I can compile and run without problem if I do the following:

- Add the folder containing the .dll to the Path environment varibale (Windows 10).
- Add the .jar as a dependency on my gradle project.

That way the API works fine.

When I move the generated jar to another computer it cannot find the dll although I include it in the jar, so the software doesn't work.

**How can I tell the generated jar that the dll it needs is in it?**

I feel like the .jar they sent me just calls the functions of the dll and assumes you added the directory to the path variable. Is there any way to make this work without needing to change the path configuration to every PC I move the jar?

I´ve already tried the answers posted here (And they don't work):

- [Gradle how to add native dependency? [Libgdx]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264221/gradle-how-to-add-native-dependency-libgdx)
- [Add native library to local jar in gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985346/add-native-library-to-local-jar-in-gradle-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way the jar loads the dll. Usually it just calls `System.loadLibrary(<libname>)` which expects the native library to be in the library search path.

If you want to load it from somewhere else you have to extract the DLL from the JAR into e.g. a temp directory or somewhere else and the load it using

`System.load(<absolute path to the dll file>)`;

Note: If you can't change the Classes in the JAR you can place the call to `System.load(..)` in a second class that is loaded before the code of the JAR is executed. AFAIR a library is only loaded once by Java, therefore if the dll of the same name is already loaded the call to `System.loadLibrary()` in the original JAR is simply ignored.

Comment: This works fine when building a jar and moving it to another PC, doesn't work for building the android apk. But I guess it's enough for now, I'll try to find a workaround for the Android case. Thank you :)

Comment: Update: I just realised I was trying to load a dll in an android project. Of course that's never going to work (Windows dll files in a Linux based Android system). So for now we'll have to stick to windows :)

Comment: Hi Mayuso ..did you get any solution .I have dll file to use in android project. any idea plz

Comment: @Manikandan Unless it is a Dot.Net based Xamarin dll file it can't be used on Android. DLLs are usually compiled for 32/64bit x86 CPU, on Android devices usually use ARM cpu that needs totally different code.

Comment: thanks for reply @Robert. I have dot.net dll file. Is any possibility  to convert as jar to use in android project. or  any idea to get jar from xamarin project

Comment: @Manikandan You can't convert a Dot.net dll to a jar file that is impossible. Use it in a Xamarin project if the dll is compatible. That is the only option.